# how to use substring in ef query within where and select statement

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

Hi there how to use `substring` in `EF` query within `where` and `select` statements?

my query does not count any record from database to execute

but in database having 13359 records

My query is below

```
string subautoassettype, subautocat, subautocat1 ;
string autoidstring;

autocat = cmbcategory.Text;
autocat1 = cmbcategory1.Text;
autocat2 = cmbcategory2.Text;              
subautoassettype = autocat.Substring(0, 3);
subautocat = autocat1.Substring(0, 3);
subautocat1 = autocat2.Substring(0, 3);

autoidstring = subautoassettype + subautocat + subautocat1 + "-";

var varmaxidcheck = cnx.item_master.Where(c => c.Item_ID.Substring(0, 9) == autoidstring)
                       .Select(gd => new { gd.Item_ID }).ToList();


if (varmaxidcheck.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var it11 in varmaxidcheck)
    {
        string kij = it11.Item_ID;
    }
}
```

Sample Output expect :

```
cnx.item_master(where c=> c.FixBooChe-0013346 == FixBooChe-).Select(fg=>fg.Item_ID);
```

Pls help me to solve this issue

Also I have include SQL query

```
select max(substring(Item_ID,11,6)) from item_master where substring(Item_ID,1,9) = 'FixEleCre';
```

Comment: You can use skip() and take().

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `==`:

```
var varmaxidcheck = cnx.item_master.Where(c => c.Item_ID.Substring(0, 9)
                                                .Contains(autoidstring))
                                   .Select(gd => new { gd.Item_ID })
                                   .ToList();
```

Because probably you don't have the exact match strings in your `Where` clause.